# Difference in behavior between Automation Schedule and Process All action on Processing page

Tags: acumatica

I have customized the GLTran DAC to have a custom field for Tax Zone and it gets populated along with Tax Category and Tax ID if the "Create Tax Transactions" check box is selected. I have also customized the "Release" to populate this Tax Zone over to the TaxTran table.

The Journal Transactions are created by a custom processing page that reads an XML file and create the Journal Transaction document and also releases it.

Everything works fine in my local instance and also on our sandbox instance.

In production, when I process the XML files using the Processing page, everything is fine. But when I create Automation Schedule, the Journal Transactions are created with Tax Zone populated and the document is released without any error. However the Tax Zone is not populated in the TaxTran table!

I don't have the same problem with Automation Schedule in my local instance or Sandbox. All these instances are of same version of Acumatica.

```
public class GLTranExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.GL.GLTran>
    {
        #region UsrTaxZoneID
        [PXDBString(10)]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<TaxZone.taxZoneID>),
              typeof(TaxZone.taxZoneID),
              typeof(TaxZone.descr))]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Tax Zone")]
        public virtual string UsrTaxZoneID { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrTaxZoneID : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
    }

public class PostGraph_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PostGraph>
    {
        public PXSelect<GLTran, Where<GLTran.batchNbr, Equal<Required<GLTran.batchNbr>>, And<GLTran.accountID, Equal<Required<GLTran.accountID>>, And<GLTran.subID, Equal<Required<GLTran.subID>>, And<GLTran.branchID, Equal<Required<GLTran.branchID>>>>>>> GLTransactions;
        public delegate void ReleaseBatchProcDelegate(Batch b, bool unholdBatch = false);
        [PXOverride]
        public void ReleaseBatchProc(Batch b, bool unholdBatch, ReleaseBatchProcDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            baseMethod(b, unholdBatch = false);
            foreach(TaxTran rec in Base.GL_GLTran_Taxes.Select(b.Module, b.BatchNbr))
            {
                GLTran glTran = GLTransactions.Select(rec.RefNbr, rec.AccountID, rec.SubID, rec.BranchID);
                GLTranExt glTranExt = PXCache<GLTran>.GetExtension<GLTranExt>(glTran);
                if (glTranExt != null)
                    rec.TaxZoneID = glTranExt.UsrTaxZoneID;
                Base.GL_GLTran_Taxes.Update(rec);
                Base.GL_GLTran_Taxes.Cache.Persist(PXDBOperation.Update);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in my case it was difference in permissions between account from which Automation Schedule was executed, and processing screen was executed. In order to fix it, I've added those lines:

```
using (new PXImpersonationContext(PX.Data.Update.PXInstanceHelper.ScopeUser))
{
                            using (new PXReadBranchRestrictedScope())
                            {
                            }
}
```

first using makes running your code from user name admin, and second using makes your code running with permissions access to necessary branches